# Using boost test with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost-test

I am trying to use Boost Test to add some much needed unit tests to my code. However I can't seem to get it to work. Right now I have the following code

```
#include <Drawing.h>
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE DrawingModelTests
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(DrawingModelTests)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE ( DrawingConstructorTest)
{
    Drawing * drawing = new Drawing;

    delete drawing;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

From what I understand I don't need to put a main or anything since boost will take care of it himself. However Visual Studio keep giving me a "entry point must be defined" error. Do I need to manually add a link to the static library or something? I am compiling as a standard .exe console application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem with VS2010 and the solution was to set 'Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point' to 'main' for the project.

Comment: I can't believe after all this time I can finally put an answer to that question ^^. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

Add /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE to the linker flags. In the project settings, this is on the Linker->System page. You can use boost as either dynamic or static library.

Comment: I had the same problem, using the Google Test library, and linking to gtest_main.lib.
This fixed that as well.

Answer (score 1):

My code is similar, and works fine. The only difference I can see is that I don't define `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN` at all. `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` tells it where to define `main`, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

I set 'Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point' to 'mainCRTStartup', which does the trick for me. (In my particular build configuration I'm statically linking boost libraries).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the way to make it work was to use boost.test as a dynamic library instead of a static library.